# Woocommerce , how to set billing_address via JS?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to have an ability to set internal woocommerce's billing_address variable on a client side via JS, jQuery and then reload page.

This move is needed for changing currency values(pls don't advise me any exts, i have already seen some).

So, when user changes input field, i need to grab new billing_address send it to woocommerce and reload page for new currency values to show on page.

Comment: At first glance to can make a PUT request to the wc/v3/customers REST endpoint with a new billing address. Or you could handle this as a POST back to an endpoint on the site that does the update and reloads the page too.

Comment: @rup, may you please be little more concrete and tell me about exact WP commands so i can find you a solution for my case.

Comment: I have learned how to work with routes. But setting billing address internally and reload page is still a mystery to me

Comment: I just found the API in the WooCommerce source code sorry. I assume there are examples calling the WooCommerce REST API, and maybe even some in the front-end using AJAX already? but I haven't done it myself.

Comment: @rup alright, anyway thx a lot friend. U get me on the right way